# Order of Pole at $s=0$ while using Residue Theorem to Invert Laplace Transform

Tags: laplace-transform, residue-calculus

I'm trying to invert the following Laplace Transform using the Residue Theorem:

$$
F(s) = \frac{K_1(\sqrt s)}{\sqrt s K_0(\sqrt s)}
$$

where $K_0()$ and $K_1()$ are the Modified Bessel Functions of the Second Kind of Orders $0$ and $1$, respectively.

There is a single pole at $s=0$. However if I treat this as a first order pole (which I'm quite sure it isn't) then using the Cauchy Residue Theorem, the inverse transform evaluates to zero. This would also be true if it is regarded as a pole of any order $\ge$ 1.

Could somebody explain a way forward? Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding your question, but just because a function is not analytic in a region, does not mean its integral cannot equal zero in a closed path around that region.

Comment: Well, in this case, the only singularity is at $s=0$, so the closed path could be the unit semicircle in the left half plane including the origin. I know from using a function sampling algorithm and the physics of the underlying problem that the inverse transform is not zero.

Comment: From a little bit of reading, I believe that what the pole at $s=0$ is not an isolated singularity, and that I have a branch cut from 0 to $\infty$. I'm not sure how to deal with this.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, Bessel functions are out of my pay grade, but good luck!